# Do I understand textureGather and textureQueryLod correctly?

Tags: opengl, glsl

There is a piece of code in OpenGL SuperBible, 7th edition, Chapter 11, topic sparsetexture:

```c
uniform sampler2D uCommittedLodTexture;
uniform sampler2D uSparseColorTexture;
vec4 sampleFromSparse(vec2 uv){
    vec4 availLod = textureGather(uCommittedLodTexture,uv);
    vec2 desireLod = textureQueryLod(uSparseColorTexture,uv);
    float maxAvailLod = max(max(availLod .x,availLod .y),max(availLod .z,availLod .w));
    float finalLod = max(desireLod.x,max(desireLod.y,maxAvailLod));
    return textureLod(uSparseColorTexture,uv,lod);// here I think it should be finalLod not lod
}
```

I cannot really get how does it work.

textureGather is a function that can return the four texels which would be used to do bilinear interpolation. The third parameter default value is zero which is x component of those chosen four texels.

But what is the functionality of textureQueryLod? Spec explains that:

> The mipmap array(s) that would be accessed is returned in the x component of the return value. The computed level-of-detail relative to the base level is returned in the y component of the return value.

Does it mean that the x value of result is the mipmap level used at the point uv? How about the y component? Is it the offset from the base level of mipmap?

textureLod returns the texel in the specified mipmap level.

I don't know whether I understand these functions correctly and this piece of code is confusing. Could someone explain a little?

Comment: It would help if you told us what the purpose of the code was.

Comment: Here is the description of the aim of this snippet of code:
" samples from a sparse texture by calculating the required level-of-detail, fetching from the committed level-of-detail texture, and then clamping the result to the highest available level (the lowest-resolution level) before sampling from the actual sparse texture. "

Answer (score 0):

In the following line,

```
vec2 desireLod = textureQueryLod(uSparseColorTexture,uv);
```

`desireLod.x` is `func(level-of-details)` that shows how finally array(s) of map maps will be accessed, while `desireLod.y` is an computed “raw” level-of-details.

Pseudocode for the the result calculation for `textureQueryLod` can be found in the [GLSL specification 8.9.1. Texture Query Functions](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf).

The specification says about the computed level-of-details:

> The level-of-detail (equation 3.18 of the
> OpenGL Specification) is obtained after any level-of-detail bias, but prior to clamping to
> [TEXTURE_MIN_LOD, TEXTURE_MAX_LOD].

while `desireLod.x` will be clamped by [TEXTURE_MIN_LOD, TEXTURE_MAX_LOD] and `maxAccessibleLevel` after the processing.

Comment: "desiredLod.x should not be more than desiredLod.y."

I guess it is possible. As textureQueryLod result's x component is the actually mipmap level used being clamped while its y component is the raw mipmap array calculated. So, when x component is clamped to be TEXTURE_MIN_LOD which is greater than 0 while y component is 0, then x component is more than y.

Comment: And I'm sorry that I missed some important information because I did not understand the code. uCommittedLodTexture is a texture that "a second, level-of-detail texture, which we can sample from to find the lowest committed level-of-detail for a given texture coordinate." So the following code is to get the lowest lod 
vec4 availLod = textureGather(uCommittedLodTexture,uv); 
But to be honest I don't know what is  lowest committed level-of-detail and how to generate it neither.

Comment: You’re right, I considered clipping only highest LODs and didn’t consider minimum

Comment: About "lowest committed level-of-detail", it's some algorithm specific stuff. It can mean the highest possible LOD value for some texture coordinates that would have a bit more sense for me. E.g. we can bake it into the texture and sample afterwards.
P.S. It seems I don't have enough context to completely understand what was intended here. Let me clean up the answer a bit